# updating vectors using function calls in julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to create a function the entries of a tree of vectors. The function should not return anything, but simply modify the  entries of the input.

For example, the function:

```
function updatevec1!(A::Matrix, v::Vector)
 v .= A*v
end
```

updates a vector after a matrix multiply (the vector `v=[1;2]` is updated to `v=[5;11]` with the matrix `A =[1,2;3,4]`). Now in my code I introduce the following recursive type.

```
abstract type gtree end

  struct gtreeleaf<:gtree
   v::Vector
  end

  struct gtreenode<:gtree
    v::Vector
    left::gtree
    right::gtree
  end
```

Now suppose I want to do the same thing for the gtreenode.

```
 function updatevec2!(A::Matrix, g::gtreenode)
   g.left.v .= A*g.left.v
 end
```

Now if want to run:

```
g = gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([1;2]), gtreeleaf([1;2]) )
updatevec2!([1,2;3,4],g)
```

The tree g is not updated! Why is that

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out on this?

EDIT: I got the code to work but only if I call it from the console. When I call it within a script, it does not do anything!

Thanks,

Nithin

Comment: Since the code is not runnable, please add the error message produced.

Comment: [Minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This has a temporary BTW. You should consider adding a cache vector and using `A_mul_B!`.

Comment: Hey all, I modified the leading post with a working example. I hope this clarifies the problem

Comment: `updatevec2!([1,2;3,4],g)` should be `updatevec2!([1 2;3 4],g)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
function updatevec!(A::Matrix, v::Vector)
  v .= A * v
end
```

Here is the result of executing the above defined function:

```
julia> x = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> A = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> updatevec!(A, x)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 11

julia> x
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 11
```

Comment: Yes that is what I want but the problem is that the same code fails if I want to use it for my gtreenode. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this should be an answer or a comment, but I can't reproduce your problem. In a fresh Julia REPL I get:

```
julia> abstract type gtree end;

julia>   struct gtreeleaf<:gtree
          v::Vector
         end;

julia>   struct gtreenode<:gtree
           v::Vector
           left::gtree
           right::gtree
         end;

julia> function updatevec2!(A::Matrix, g::gtreenode)
          g.left.v .= A*g.left.v
        end
updatevec2! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g = gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([1;2]), gtreeleaf([1;2]) );

julia> updatevec2!([1 2;3 4],g)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 11

julia> g
gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([5, 11]), gtreeleaf([1, 2]))
```

as expected.

**UPDATE (according to OP's EDIT):**

Also works in a script. This is my `test.jl`:

```
abstract type gtree end;

struct gtreeleaf<:gtree
          v::Vector
         end;

struct gtreenode<:gtree
           v::Vector
           left::gtree
           right::gtree
         end;

function updatevec2!(A::Matrix, g::gtreenode)
          g.left.v .= A*g.left.v
        end

g = gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([1;2]), gtreeleaf([1;2]) );

println(g)
updatevec2!([1 2;3 4],g)

println(g)
```

When I run it I get output

```
gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([1, 2]), gtreeleaf([1, 2]))
gtreenode([1], gtreeleaf([5, 11]), gtreeleaf([1, 2]))
```

again as expected.

Comment: The same for me - it works (tested on Julia Version 0.7.0-DEV.3354). Only note - as it is corrected in this answer the way to write a matrix is `[1 2;3 4]` not `[1,2; 3,4]`.